# An unknown error occurred(-50) when drag iPhone app to iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

When i am dragging my iPhone app to iTunes for testing in device then i got an alert like"The app ' Sample' could not be added to your iTunes library because an error occurred.An unknown error occurred(-50)".How to solve this issue?Please help me

Comment: Check this : http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1583

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and resolved it this way:

In iTunes go to Preferences/General and make sure the Apps box is ticked.

Then you need to reorganise your iTunes Library and this will take time depending on how big its size is. Click on File, select Library and Organize Library. Tick both boxes on (Consolidate fle and Reorganize files in the folder "iTunes Media". Click OK.

The operation will now take some time and all your files will be reorganised on the volume you selected as the iTunes locations in iTune Preferences/Advanced. The organisation will follow the structure described here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3847

If your apps still don't show, then you can move them manually from the Mobile Applications folder to the Apps page selection in iTunes. The -50 error will not occur again.

I suspect the error occurs to begin with because of an alteration on the locations of the iTunes library files (after a backup/restore for instance) and that introduces permission problems.